# multiple json data to use in same return function in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a page of a food application. On this page I have to show all the food categories of food.

**foodScreen.js**

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

    <View style={styles.ListView}>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <AllCategory icon={"home-outline"} name={"Household"} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"basket-outline"} name={"Grocery"} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"ios-podium"} name={"Milk"} />
        </View>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.ListView}>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"ios-rose"} name={"chilled"} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"hardware-chip"} name={"Drinks"} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"cloud"} name={"Pharmacy"} />
        </View>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.ListView}>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"fast-food"} name={"Frozen Food"} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"football"} name={"Vegetable"} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <AllCategory icon={"bulb"} name={"Meat"} />
        </View>
    </View>
    
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see the that I have repeated `<View style={styles.ListView}>  ..... </View>` 3 times to get 3 rows as shown in image below.

[image]

But I want to take data from json and then show all the categories on this page.

For this I have made a json file.

**data.js**

```
export const PRODUCT_DATA = [
    {
        name: 'abc',
        price: 90,
        weight: '1 kg',
        currency: 'INR',
        liked: true,
        image: require('../assets/images/carrots/Rectangle238.png')
    },
    {
        name: 'bce',
        price: 10,
        weight: '1 kg',
        currency: 'USD',
        liked: false,
        image: require('../assets/images/mango/Rectangle234.png')
    },
    {
        AllCategoriesComponent: [
            {
                icon: "home-outline",
                name: "Household",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "basket-outline",
                name: "Grocery",
                shape: false,
            },
            {
                icon: "ios-podium",
                name: "Milk",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "ios-rose",
                name: "chilled",
                shape: false,
            },
            {
                icon: "hardware-chip",
                name: "Drinks",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "cloud",
                name: "Pharmacy",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "fast-food",
                name: "Frozen Food",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "football",
                name: "Vegetable",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "bulb",
                name: "Meat",
                shape: true,
            },
        ]
    },
];
```

So For this I changed my code in **foodScreen.js** to :

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    {PRODUCT_DATA[2].AllCategoriesComponent.map((item, index) => {
        // console.log(item.liked);
        return (
            <View style={styles.ListView}>
                <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <AllCategory icon={item.icon} name={item.name} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
                    <AllCategory icon={item.icon} name={item.name} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
                    <AllCategory icon={item.icon} name={item.name} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    })}
</ScrollView>
```

But I am getting undesired output as given in image below.

[image]

I am not able to figure out how can I achieve the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have to put `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on your `styles.ListView`. So in your style made following changes :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // your other styles,
  ListView: {
    // ... your listview style,
    flexWrap: 'wrap', // add this
  }
});
```

Now, in your scroll view you have to write just one `View` as following :

```js
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <View style={styles.ListView}>
    {PRODUCT_DATA[2].AllCategoriesComponent.map((item, index) => {
      // console.log(item.liked);
      return (
          <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <AllCategory icon={item.icon} name={item.name} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      );
    })}
  </View>
</ScrollView>;
```

Please notice that I have moved `<View style={styles.ListView}>` out of the map function.